# can not get current props in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, frontend

I use `useEffect` with parameter `props.quizStep`.
But **fn**(keydown event listener function) cannot get current `props.quizStep`.

Why it cannot get current props?

Here is my code.

```
    const moveBirdKeyboard = React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('moveBirdKeyboard props.quizStep', props.quizStep);
        let fn = (e: any) => {
            console.log('props.quizStep', props.quizStep);
            moveBirdEvent(e);
        }
        if(eventListener.current === false) {
            (window as any).addEventListener('keydown', _.throttle(fn,10)); //_.throttle(fn,1000));
            eventListener.current = true;
        } 
    }, [props.quizStep]);
```

Comment: What do you mean it cannot get the current props? Does it throw an error, is the value always undefined or something else?

Comment: When I occur 'keydown' event, function "fn" is can not get changed props. / When 'keydown' event, "fn" can not get changed props.

Comment: assuming you are using a ref for your event listener, it appears to me your event listener is registered once only - even if the effect runs multiple times and a new fn with updated props is created. And since its a closure, it has the - now stale - props from the time it was created. Its also always neccessary to remove the listener on the return of the useEffect in order to clean it up.

Comment: @Dean
Thanks Dean. You are right. It is closure. I remove event listener and re-create event listener when props.quizStep changed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the useEffect hook to a variable, as it says its a hook, not a property. Instead of that you need to create a function which properties can be attached to a hook.

A good example from the reactJS documentation:

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `Clicked ${count} times`;
  });
```

Comment: I used const variable, it is to make JSDOC. I don't use moveBirdKeyboard directly in my code.

Comment: How is it useful for jsdoc when this variable is just `undefined`?

Comment: I'm going to write jsdoc comment above this code.

Comment: and how's it? you got it?

Comment: Without variable, jodoc doesn't bundle my code to html document :(